# Remove row when value is found in another row and replace value with string SQL Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, vba, amazon-web-services, merge, amazon-redshift

I want to reduce rows into smaller rows.
I have some IDs that are found in other rows and I want to remove those duplicates but also concatenate to have the list of IDs that are related to each other.

Here is my current output:

```
|         IDs          |
|----------------------|
|1147457338            |
|1147457340            |
|1150006529            |
|1150012541, 1175373594|
|1150012541, 20296677  |
|1150012542            |
|1150012543            |
|1150012543, 1150012542|
|1175373593, 1150006529|
|1175373594, 1175373593|
|1275678231            |
|20296677              |
|782676061             |
|782676061, 1147457338 |
```

The first ID in Row 4 is found in Row 5. Since that value is found there, I want to merge them in one row like this:

```
|               IDs              |
|--------------------------------|
|1150012541, 1175373594, 20296677|
```

And so on with the all.
Since I'm not an expert with SQL, the only thing that came to my mind was to do a code with VB.net that can be executed in Excel and it works just as I was expecting.
Below the code in case it helps to understand what I want to achieve:

```
Sub idMerge()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long

        With Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet
            lRow = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count 'Last Row

            For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
                If InStr(.Range("A" & i).Value, ",") = 0 Then 'If it is only one ID and it's found in another row, delete row
                    If .Range("A" & i - 1 & ":A1").Find(.Range("A" & i).Value,,, XlLookAt.xlPart) IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                Else 'If there are multiple IDs, look for each one in another rows and if it's found, the ID found is replace with the whole cell content and deletes the row
                    For Each id In Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, ", ")
                        If .Range("A1:B" & i - 1).Find(id,,, XlLookAt.xlPart) IsNot Nothing Then
                            Replace(.Range("A1:A" & i - 1).Find(id,,, XlLookAt.xlPart).Value, id, .Range("A" & i).Value)
                            .Range("A1:A" & i - 1).Find(id,,, XlLookAt.xlPart).Value = Replace(.Range("A1:A" & i - 1).Find(id,,, XlLookAt.xlPart).Value, id, .Range("A" & i).Value)
                            .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next id
                End If
            Next i
        End With
End Sub
```

The output using this code returns this:

```
|                        IDs                             |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
|782676061, 1147457338                                   |
|1147457340                                              |
|1150012541, 20296677, 1175373594, 1175373593, 1150006529|
|1150012543, 1150012542                                  |
|1275678231                                              |
```

Which is EXACTLY what I'm looking for with SQL only

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**
I posted another question a few days ago (linked to that post) which I haven't received a solution. But the closest I could get to that question is to get only 2 geometry that are connected to each other, but I cannot connect all of them. Here is what I made to achieve that output:

```
WITH geoSet AS (
  SELECT geoID, vector 
  FROM geometry
  WHERE geoID IN (1147457338, 1147457340, 782676061, 20296677, 1175373594, 1175373593, 1150006529, 1150012542, 1150012541, 1150012543, 1275678231)
  )
  SELECT DISTINCT LISTAGG(geoID, ', ') AS path
  FROM (
  (SELECT geoID, 
  CONCAT(SPLIT_PART(vector,',',1),')') AS startEndPoint
  FROM geoSet
  )
  
  UNION
  
  (SELECT geoID, 
  CONCAT('LINESTRING (',TRIM(SPLIT_PART(vector,',',LEN(vector)-LEN(REPLACE(vector,',',''))+1))) AS startEndPoint
  FROM geoSet
  )
  )GROUP BY startEndPoint ORDER BY path
```

Comment: How are you producing the first table? Is it produced by SQL that is combining multiple rows into a single row? If so, it might be easier to come up with a solution _before_ they are combined into one row.

Comment: I notice that the first row is `1147457338` and the last row is `782676061, 1147457338`. How would you want this type of situation to be handled? In fact, should the last two rows also be combined?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the first table was made using another code. I asked something some time ago here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75338734/return-a-list-of-ids-in-which-geometry-connect-to-each-other-with-sql-amazon-red/75342855#75342855.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein As for your second comment, since the ID in the first Row is found in the last row, then only remove the first row since the last one has two IDs

Comment: I would recommend that the "reduction" logic be done in the original query if possible. Also, have a careful think about what you want the 'removal' code to do. For example, if one row has `A, B` and another row has `C, B` does that mean the output should be `A, B, C` or `C, A, B` etc. It's actually quite a complex requirement you are wanting to solve.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I tried with the original query and it's also very complex. That output was the closest I could get. I'll add the code I used to get that first output. As for your examples, I don't really care in which order, it can be `A, B, C`, or `C, B, A`, or `B, C, A`, it doesn't really matter the order.